# Do chord voicings matter for the intervals

Tags: guitar, scales, intervals

If I'm playing in C Major the C Major open guitar chord and then I want to play the 5th to this chord, what chord should I play ?

I know there's a rule that says "*to determine interval between 2 notes you count from the lowest note to the highest*", and I assume that when someone says "give me the 5th of C Major open chord" it means a chord whose root note is a 5th interval apart from the root note C. So, following this logic I can tell that F Major bar chord on 1th fret fits perfectly:

[image: F Major bar chord on 1th fret]

since from F on 1st fret of 6th string to C on 3rd fret on 5th string the interval is P5.
But, at the same time I can build F Major chord differently, in other words use other voicing:

[image: other F Major voicing]

And in this voicing interval between C on 3rd fret of 5th string to the root F on 3rd fret of 4th string is P4.

So, in first voicing the interval is P5 and in second vocing the interval is P4.
And the question is: "Who is the real P5 to our C Major" ? Can voicings change the function of the chord (P5 to P4 etc.) ?

Comment: A 5th up from C is G, btw [guitar strings are mainly a 4th apart]. I don't actually understand the rest of what you're saying, sorry.

Comment: @Tetsujin,

F on 1st fret of 6th string is also 5th from the C (on 3rd fret of 5th string). Which chord considered to be 5th then F or G ?

Comment: Ah, I see what you're doing - the F is a 5th *below* the C, which is going to confuse you to start with. For now, always count *up*, or if you count down, start from 8 & count backwards.

Comment: Several topics have gotten mixed up here. When we talk about “intervals,“ the context is usually talking about the distance between individual notes, not chords. We also use language like “the fifth of“ when talking about the function of cords within a key, as in “the fifth of C major is G.“ And then we also use it when talking about the notes within the chord itself, in which one of the notes is the “root,“ and the other two notes in a simple cord are the “third“ and the “5th.“

Comment: This can't be answered as it stands, as it's asked using skewed facts, and uses distorted information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advice you're working with -- "to determine interval between 2 notes you count from the lowest note to the highest" -- is incorrect.  In fact, you can count in either direction and get the same result, but the direction is of course the opposite.  If you count up from C to G, you get an ascending perfect fifth.  If you count down from G to C you get a descending perfect fifth.  In both cases the interval spans five letters (counting inclusively) and seven semitones (not counting inclusively).

On the other hand, if you count down from C to G (or up from G to C) you have changed the interval.  (This change is known as "inversion.")

English uses ordinal numbers for intervals and for scale degrees.  Because we identify the components of a chord by the interval between the root and the component in question, we also use ordinal numbers to identify them.

As mentioned above, intervals can be either ascending or descending.  A perfect fifth above C is G.  A perfect fifth *below* C is F.  But because scale degrees and chord components are always identified by the ascending interval, the fifth degree of a C scale is always G.  The fifth of a C chord (and of C7, Cm, Cm7, Cmaj7) is always G, regardless of the chord's voicing.

To identify *the chord built on the fifth degree of the scale* we use a roman numeral, and we speak it *as a cardinal number.*  Therefore, "the V chord" is pronounced "the five chord," and in C major (and C minor for that matter) it is always G, because as described above the fifth degree of the scale is always G.

Therefore, your question

> If I'm playing in C Major the C Major open guitar chord and then I want to play the 5th to this chord, what chord should I play?"

... doesn't make a lot of sense, because the fifth of any chord isn't another chord; it's just a single pitch.  Since you're asking what chord to play, I suspect that the question is a mistranslation and that it ought to be "...and then I want to play the V chord...," but if it isn't a mistranslation then the second half of the question should be"...what note should I play?"

---

In the comments, it has been asserted that the major third is so called because it is the third degree of the major scale.  While this is not particularly relevant to this question about "fifth" and "five," it seems like a good opportunity to point out that the reverse is true: the major scale is so called because its third degree is a major third.  I recently addressed this with respect to major chords in my answer to [Why is a minor chord or key considered to be "lesser?"](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/129210/2257)

Comment: "you can count in either direction and get the same result" But if you count up three letters in the scale of C you get E, a major 3rd. If you count down three letters you get A. And A-C is a minor 3rd. Because we name intervals by counting up from the lower note, no matter what order the notes are played in. The 'perfect' intervals, 4ths, 5ths and octaves, remain perfect if you count down diatonically. Other intervals don't.   Main point - however you arrive it, from below or above - an interval is always NAMED by counting up from the lower note.

Comment: From what I've understood:

1. the definiton of V chord is bound by scale context, it's not just the 7 half-steps from root notes of chords.

Comment: 2. there's quite an important notion of octave ignorance where we always count from the scale tonic to the note in question, even if notes are in different octaves like F2 and C3, if C is a tonic, then we'll count from C to F and say that F is P4, and it stays P4 no matter the octave it's in (maybe compound intervals add something to this, I didn't think of it yet). So, when we're talking in context of chords and their progression/function in scale, we count intervals this way.

Comment: It's still super confusing, since there's a notion of interval in the context of scale, and the notion of interval like a distance in half-steps between notes in question.

Comment: @Laurence the given rule is "to determine interval between 2 notes...."  To determine the interval between C and and the E above it, you can start at C and count up or you can start at E and count down.  Why would anyone trying to identify the interval between C and the E above it "count down three letters" starting at C??  It makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @Laurence to say "we name intervals by counting up from the lower note, no matter what order the notes are played in" makes no sense.  Just as it's 60 miles from London to Cambridge as well as 60 miles from Cambridge to London, counting C-D-E gives the same result as counting E-D-C: it's a third.  E is a major third above C; C is a major third below E.  There is nothing about the name "major third" that implies direction _per se,_ so there is no reason to say that the interval is named with respect to a particular direction.

Comment: @phoog And it's called a major 3rd because E is the 3re note of a C major scale.  That's just how the system of interval naming works.  If the top note's in the major scale starting on the bottom note, it's a major interval.  One semitone smaller, it's minor. Another, diminished.  One semitone larger, augmented.  Special case for the 'perfect' intervals, they contract straight to diminished.  We all learnt this in Theory#101.  It's a conventional naming system, not deep harmonic analysis.

Comment: @oyevtushe a perfect fifth is always 7 half steps, but seven half steps isn't always a perfect fifth.  It could be a diminished sixth, for example.  F is always the 4th degree of the C major scale, but any given F could be a fifth below some given C, or a twelfth below, or an 11th above.  The functional role of F in the key of C is typically expressed by IV from its position in the ascending C scale, abstractly, which is why specific voicings don't affect this.

Comment: @Laurence no, that's backwards.  The major scale is called a major scale because its third degree is a major third.  It's called a major third because it spans three letters and is the larger of the two intervals that may be obtained by spanning three letters.  This concept arose centuries before the major scale even existed as a theoretical construct, and it does not depend on the major scale for its existence (nor does it depend 8n direction).

Comment: @phoog  There are a lot more than two intervals obtainable from a span of three letters!   And that's without getting into double-sharps or flats.  Counting up from the bottom note isn't deep-level analysis, it's just an easy way of working out an interval's name.  Otherwise you've got to memorise a whole LOT of semitone-counts!

Comment: @Laurence well yes, I forgot to mention the additional constraint _without accidentals,_ or, if you prefer, _within any diatonic scale,_ in which case there are only two.  Comparing interval size to the corresponding degree of a major scale is indeed an easy way of identifying interval quality, but it shouldn't be misunderstood as the reason behind interval quality names, nor does it imply that interval measurement somehow works only in one direction.  And memorizing the sizes of the intervals in the major scale _is_ memorizing a lot of semitone counts.

Comment: @Laurence you can also reduce the memorization burden by figuring the quality of sixths and sevenths by inverting them to thirds and seconds and taking the opposite of the quality of the corresponding interval.  Then, for the imperfect intervals, you only have to memorize seconds and thirds.  It sounds cumbersome described like this, but in fact I was thinking of major and minor sevenths as being one and two half steps shy of an octave for years before I could quickly pull 11 and 10 out of my head in association with those intervals.

Comment: @phoog "And memorizing the sizes of the intervals in the major scale is memorizing a lot of semitone counts."  I suppose it would be!  I've never bothered to.  I just know my scales and key signatures.